# any disadvantage on setting form value through jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have form with lot of elements, most are select box, check box, radio . for example below selectbox `chart[type]` I am setting it value through php

```
<select name="chart[type]" id="chart_type" >                         
       <option value="nps" <?php if ( $chart_data['chart']['type'] == 'nps' ) echo ' select="selected" '; ?> >NPS Barchart</option>
       <option value="score" <?php if ( $chart_data['chart']['type'] == 'score' ) echo ' select="selected" '; ?>>Number/score</option>
       <option value="top5" <?php if ( $chart_data['chart']['type'] == 'top5' ) echo ' select="selected" '; ?>>Top 5</option>
</select>
```

I tried a code to set from value using jQuery

```
<select name="chart[type]" id="chart_type" >                         
    <option value="nps" >NPS Barchart</option>
    <option value="score">Number/score</option>
    <option value="top5">Top 5</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function(){
            $('[name="chart[type]"]').val( 
                 '<?php echo  $chart_data['chart']['type']; ?>'
            );
    });
</script>
```

I feel code is much cleaner . I am planning to change all forms code refill to this way . I would like to know any disadvantage of using second ? .. my application is for chart rendering it will not work, if JavaScript is disabled !

Comment: THe obvious one is that it won't work when JS is disabled in browser

Comment: @Mchl my application will not work, if JavaScript is disabled . Application is for chart rendering

Comment: It's more work for the browser and the page will render slower.

Comment: @Barmar: oh come on! JS engines nowadays are fast enough to render 3D graphics in real time.

Comment: @Barmar unless there's loads going on, you won't really notice such a trivial bit of code

Comment: Mostly it just seems pointless. It's easy to do it in PHP. Only problem is you mistyped; `select=` should be `selected=`.

Comment: If you want "clean", then store the data in a PHP array and generate it in a loop rather then copy/pasting your `if` statement.

Comment: My general philosophy is to do anything server-side that's reasonable, client-side stuff should be for things that have to be done there for responsive websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your application will not work at all without JS disabled, there is really nothing that could be considered a disadvantage to this approach. In fact, it might be easier this way to covert your select boxes to have values loaded by AJAX calls.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PHP and have no real reason to use JavaScript to print HTML, I'd keep using PHP. Mixing like that is not a good idea, you should really consider AJAX. But you can make your PHP code more maintainable and dynamic:

```
<?php

$data = array(
  'nps' => 'NPS Barchart',
  'score' => 'Number/score',
  'top5' => 'Top 5'
);

$options = '';

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  $selected = $chart_data['chart']['type'] == $key ? 'selected' : '';
  $options .= sprintf('<option class="%1$s" %2$s>%3$s</option>', $key, $selected, $value);
}

echo sprintf('<select name="chart[type]" id="chart_type">%s</select>', $options);
```

Comment: designer is not much knowledge in php . he can read easily second one!

Comment: IMO a designer that doesn't know how to code shouldn't drive your decisions on how to code. Do what's best for the application. The mixed JS-PHP combo is definitely not needed in this case TBH.

Answer (score 0):

The disadvantage is that your code now has a dependency on JavaScript and jQuery. Some (very few % of people) have JavaScript disabled, and so won't have anything selected by default

It's not best practice, but I must admit that I have used JavaScript in similar ways in the past simply for convenience/ease. It feels somewhat "hacky"

Comment: my application is for chart rendering, it will not work if js is disabled !

Answer (score 0):

Using two languages in one block isn't always a bad thing. But when your one line of

`'<?php echo  $chart_data['chart']['type']; ?>'`

Become more than one line, it will start to look rather messy.

When that happen you can do the below.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
            // assignment from php
            var chart_type = '<?php echo  $chart_data['chart']['type']; ?>';

            $('[name="chart[type]"]').val(chart_type);
    });
</script>
```

Anyway, it will be best if you can convert your application to perform ajax posting so you won't have to setting form value through this way.